# Cannot set default app for user with System Administration Profile

Tags: lightning-apps, profile, system-admin

I have an account with System Administration Profile. I set the default app to the Admin System app like the picture below:

[image]

However, when I log out and log in again, the account still keeps the Setup page as the first display screen. I can still set up the default app normally for other profiles except for System Administration. Is there any way to create a default app for System Administration Profile? Please help, thank you.

UPDATE: I have changed the default app and saved it again then log out. My org can display the default app the first time I log in but not for the second time.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning default app will only allow System Administration to see the app when they login to Salesforce for the first time. However, when a user switches apps during his session, logs out and logs back in, the user is taken back to the last App he/she was in.

System admins are allowed to set a default app in profiles, Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdWCeUAN/default-app-landing-app).